# $Y_n = V_n + a V_{n-1}$, $V_n$ iid with $\mathbb{E}[V_n] = 0$ and variance $\sigma_V^2$, find autocorrelation for $Y_n$

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance, correlation

I’m struggling with how to express the solution to the question in terms of the variance.

this is the solution$$\mathbb{E}(Y_n Y_{n+m}) = \sigma_V^2 \cdot [(1+n(n+m))\delta(m) +n\delta(m+1)+ (n+m)\delta(m-1)]$$
whereas I got
$$R_{Y}(n,n+m) = R_V(m) (n^2+1) + nR_V(m-1) + nR_V(m+1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V_n$ are i.i.d., note that $Y_n$ and $Y_{n +m}$ are independent for $|m| \geq 2$. Consequently, $\mathbb{E}[Y_n Y_{n+m}] = \mathbb{E}[Y_n] \mathbb{E}[Y_{n+m}] = 0$ as $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = 0$ for all $n$.

For $m = 0$, we have,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y_n^2] = \mathbb{E}[(V_n + a V_{n-1})^2] = \mathbb{E}[V_n^2] + a^2 \mathbb{E}[V_{n-1}^2] + 2a \mathbb{E}[V_n] \mathbb{E}[V_{n-1}] = \sigma_V^2 (1 + a^2).
\end{align*}

For $m = 1$, we have,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y_n Y_{n+1}] & = \mathbb{E}[(V_n + a V_{n-1})(V_{n+1} + a V_{n})] \\
& =  \mathbb{E}[V_n] \mathbb{E}[V_{n+1}] + a \mathbb{E}[V_n^2] + a \mathbb{E}[V_{n+1}] \mathbb{E}[V_{n-1}] + a^2 \mathbb{E}[V_n] \mathbb{E}[V_{n-1}] \\
& = a \sigma_V^2.
\end{align*}

The $m = -1$ is identical to that of $m = 1$. On combining all of them, we obtain,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y_n Y_{n+m}] = \sigma_V^2 [a^2 \delta(m) + a\delta(m+1) + a\delta(m-1)].
\end{align*}

I am not sure why the solution shows a dependence on $n$ and $m$, apart from the $\delta$ functions.

Comment: Thank you! I made an error and accidentally transcribed a where it should’ve been n, but I now understand the logic behind your solution and will try to apply it.

Comment: Ah okay! The solution with $a$ replaced with $n$ follows closely along the above solution.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yjZZN59

Comment: yes! sorry! I understood the method from your explanation and was able to solve it though, thank you so much!